# How to open a new ticket on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Seems impossible to find the section to open a new ticket with Heroku.

The button doesn't seem to be able to be found.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the portal to ask a new question here:

https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new

Comment: Your link is now leading to the same maze as OP stumbled upon. It looks like now it is not possible to inform them quickly about an issue that is affecting their clients but not yet present on the status page. That's simply ridiculous.

Comment: Not any more, just a redirect now to Heroku's 'solution finder' and seemingly endless self help loop with no new ticket links.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Use [https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?id=\](https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?id=%5C)<topic id> to create a new ticket.

---

After a little detective work:

At https://www.heroku.com/contact there is a link to https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?id=2 for creating a billing support ticket.

The 'create a ticket' link at Support takes you to https://help.heroku.com/?t=true. On that page are a number of topics (currently 13) with links of the form [https://help.heroku.com/n/\](https://help.heroku.com/n/%5C)<topic id>/<topic description>. Choose your topic and use the id number in the url above.

Just entering https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new now re-routes you to the 'create a ticket link'

Left as an exercise: compile a full list of topic id's and descriptions.

Left as another exercise: write a Haiku on the frustrations of customer service infinite self-help loops.